# Why the limitation on exporting an interface by default in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I'm using TypeScript 1.5 beta, and I'm trying to export an interface as the default export. The following code causes an error in both Visual Studio and WebStorm:

```
export default interface Foo {...}
```

However, the following code works fine:

```
interface Foo {...}
export default Foo;
```

Is this by design, is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** Thank you for your answer. It begs the question, however, so what is the accepted way to import an interface using the ES6 module syntax?

This works:

```
// Foo.ts
export interface Foo {}

// Bar.ts
import {Foo} from 'Foo'; // Notice the curly braces

class Bar {
    constructor(foo:Foo) {}
}
```

But, since that works, why not allow a default export and save the curly braces?

```
// Foo.ts
export default interface Foo {}

// Bar.ts
import Foo from 'Foo'; // Notice, no curly braces!

class Bar {
    constructor(foo:Foo) {}
}
```

Comment: You should probably raise this as a bug.

Answer (score 31):

TypeScript v2.4.0 allows `export default interface`. [Here is the pull-request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/commit/5ef6192c20c051d3b03bc0059b7a1e0a86163379) that introduced the change.

We can now do both of these:

```
// Foo.ts
export interface Foo { }

// Bar.ts
export default interface Bar { }    

// Baz.ts
import { Foo } from "./foo";
import Bar from "./bar";

export class Baz implements Foo, Bar 
{

}
```

Comment: `@babel/preset-typescript` does not seem to support it yet