# Cannot import exported interface - export not found

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I reduced the issue to this example:

**test.model.ts**

```
export class A {
    a: number;
}

export interface B {
    b: number;
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { A, B } from './test.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '<h1>test</h1>'
})
export class TestComponent {

    //This works fine
    @Input() foo: A;

    //Does NOT work - export 'B' was not found in './test.model'
    @Input() bar: B;

}
```

When I want to use an **interface** I get following warning:

```
WARNING in ./src/app/.../test.component.ts
21:76 export 'B' was not found in './test.model'
```

However, using a **class** is OK. Any hint?

**UPDATE**: It seems to be somehow related to this issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2977

Comment: Isn't this already answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270084/why-the-limitation-on-exporting-an-interface-by-default-in-typescript

Comment: I don't think so - that issue deals with default export that I don't use. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ah sorry, didn't read properly

Comment: Is this a runtime or compile error?

Comment: It is a compile warning.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GzJ4A2uVaNezKf4Xhmpt?p=preview works fine here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yesterday I found another question here and the solution it to declare the exported interface it a separate file. With one interface per file, it works for me without any warnings.

Comment: This worked for me and here's an explanation of why: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034#issuecomment-302666897

Comment: I am getting this error even if it is the only interface in the file though (but there is also other exports, such as a `mergeInterfaces(left, right)` method). This seems like an honest bug, not a feature.

Answer (score 52):

The root cause is in Typescript and transpilation. Once TypeScript code is transpiled, interfaces/types are gone. They don't exist anymore in the emitted files.

While the types are erased, the imports/exports aren't necessarily. The reason is that there are ambiguities and that the compiler doesn't always know for sure whether something that is exported is a type or a value.

When using TypeScript `3.8` and up, all you need to do in your `test.component.ts` is simply this:

```
import { A } from './test.model';
import type { B } from './test.model';
```

Answer (score 24):

You might also be able to fix that by using a new feature in `Typescript 3.8` called [Type-Only Imports and Exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-exports).

So it means you can import the problematic type `A` like this:

```
import { B } from './test.model';
import type { A } from './test.model';
```

Also be aware that Angular only seems to support Typescript 3.8 from [Angular 9.1 and above](https://blog.angular.io/version-9-1-of-angular-now-available-typescript-3-8-faster-builds-and-more-eb292f989428).

I also recommend reading [this "Leveraging Type-Only imports and exports with TypeScript 3.8" post for more details](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/leveraging-type-only-imports-and-exports-with-typescript-3-8-5c1be8bd17fb).

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to removing the warning is the slightly distasteful hack of [a union of the interface with itself](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034#issuecomment-304406270).

```
@Input() bar: B | B;
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
@Input() bar: B | null;
```

Using Angular 4.4.3 + Typescript 2.3.4

Comment: This will work if you're allowing `null` as a valid input value (otherwise it'll violate type safety).

Answer (score 1):

I have this error with an interface defined in it's own `myinterface.ts` file and then running Karma tests. I don't see the issue when running `ng serve`. Adding 1 more `export` of an unused const to the `myinterface.ts` file solved the issue:

```
export interface IMyInterface {
    ...
}
export const A = 'A';
```